How to read boot logs when stuck in a boot loop?
My Sony Xperia 1 V is using an unofficial build of LineageOS (rooted with Magisk) and after a few weeks of working fine, became stuck in a bootloop. I can access Fastboot and Recovery fine, and I still have the PIN and all my fingers (enrolled for fingerprints). LineageOS's Recovery also allows me to start a root shell via ADB from a PC connected with a USB cable, as well as modify the system partition (either directly when mounted read-write, or via ADB sideload).
How can I read the logs from the regular boot? I cannot access my data partition (yet). When I'm on an ADB shell in Recovery, there is no /proc/last_kmsg and my /sys/fs/pstore is mounted but empty.
Can I somehow force the system to log to some specific location while booting (or maybe it does log somewhere but I don't know where to look)?
Or maybe instead I could get rid of the splash boot animation to see the logs instead of it? I believe I can add some kernel arguments by carefully writing them in the header block of vendor_boot_a and vendor_boot_b partitions.

The adb interface is enabled way before Android has loaded the UI. So if you are lucky adb is already available before your phone starts to reboot. However it can get tricky starting adb at the right time when adb is already available but before the reboot.

@Robert I tried adb logcat on a connected laptop, but I'm only getting "waiting for device". When I tried adb shell at some time, I got a "no permissions" error. I even tried changing /system/build.props to ro.secure=0, ro.adb.secure=0, persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb and persist.service.adb.enable=1, but it didn't help.
